# Adding a key to a foreach created array not adding all values

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach($_POST['door_check'] as $door_check) 
{
    $_SESSION['front_door']['door'] = $door_check;
}
```

I have this little section of code that checks how many boxes were checked and then creates an array of the check box values.

The thing is, when I add that 'door' key, the array only adds one value no matter how many checkboxes were checked. When I just leave it empty, it adds all of them like [0], [1], [2] etc

Why is this?,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `foreach()` loops overwrites old variable each time. You need to make your session variable an array, for example

```
foreach($_POST['door_check'] as $door_check) 
{
    $_SESSION['front_door']['door'][] = $door_check;
}
```

*edit*: Don't forget to validate that data when you save it for later use.

Comment: Was not aware of the over writing. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['door_check'] as $door_check) {
    $_SESSION['front_door']['door'][] = $door_check;
}
```

or maybe even:

```
$_SESSION['front_door']['door'] = $_POST['door_check'];
```